# Is there a way to control entry sort order?

Tags: channel-entries

I am very familiar with the standard methods for sorting channel entries. However, I have a client that wants more control than the standard alpha ascending / descending or the by entry date.

Is there a way that users can drag entries to appear in a specific order or some other way to control the order in which they appear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Low Reorder](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder) was created for this exact purpose.

Comment: Low, thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay without the dragging, you can create a dropdown order field with numbers set up like 01,02,03 etc...

Then you can order the entries by that field.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10" orderby="{name_of_field_HERE}"}
```

Not as elegant as dragging but another way to set things up if you are on a budget.

Comment: Yes, I have done this approach in the past, but it is as you say, not as elegant. Thanks.

Comment: I have an issue.I have a points table and there are two teams locked at the same point.The one with more goals needs to be on top..any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: Best to post a new question if you need direction.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Selected Items: http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/selected_items. Perhaps not as slick as Reorder, but free.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be achieved with Playa.

EDIT/UPDATE:
yes, my initial answer wasn't too detailed. Hadn't had any coffee then. So, here we go:

I have used Playa inside a Matrix fieldtpye on a CartThrob driven ecommerce site to give admins the power to sort products with Playa. On the homepage I set it up like this:

```
{/your_matrix_field}
     <div class="products">
          <h2>{cell_1}</h2>
          <ul class="noGrid">
              {cell_2}
              {stash:embed name="snippets:productdiv" process="start"}         
              {/cell_2}
          </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
{/your_matrix_field}
```

{cell_2} is the Playa field. The superadmin can then pretty conveniently choose which products (or better which product categories) will be available in the Matrix/Playa fieldtype.

Admins will then be able to search for products, add them to the Matrix row, sort them in the added products column and as a added bonus they will be able to add multiple Matrix Rows with different heading, for example "Sale", "New" or whatever.

This is all working very nice and is really flexible. The site is online, if somebody is interested in seeing it live or needs more informations, feel free to express this wish. I just don't want to paste urls here as I don't know on how this would be recieved here and I think looking at the frontend of some site doesn't really helps that much neither.

Cheers, Marc

Comment: Can you expand a little on how playa could be used to sort entries? Playa doesn't solve the exact problem the OP has, so it would be worth explaining the options and trade offs here.